# How to target a specific iPhone size when developing in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I've built my 4 inch screen and 3.5 inch screen apps in Xcode 5.1.1. Yesterday I downloaded Xcode 6.1 to build those same apps for iPhone 6 and 6+. I'm not using auto layout (because it messes with my UIImageViews) and to use size classes you must also use auto layout. So I can't use size classes either. When I use that 1 storyboard for  4.7inch and 5.5 inch iPhone storyboards that are in Assistant Editor, i want to move an image in only 4.7 inch but instead the image moves in both 4.7 inch and 5.5 inch iPhones. How do I make it that the image moves only in 4.7 inch instead of both?

Comment: You should figure out why auto layout is "messing" with your image views (which it shouldn't if you're using them correctly) so you can use auto layout and size classes.

Comment: For some reason when the simulators load up my intro page glitches for a 1 second and gets back to normal. It's not supposed to glitch. Without auto layout there is no glitch at all. So i just don't use auto layout. Do you know how i can target only 1 one of the phones to move images instead of both phones without using auto layout and size classes?